# Bluetooth connection in Android studio

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to develop two apps on android studio, each to run on different Android device. I want to exchange data between those two using Bluetooth. I have followed the Android Developer documentation and I did the following: search for devices, establish the RFCOMM channel, connected both devices. However, I cannot see the data sent or received. One app is a client to initiate the connection, the other app is both client and server side. Once connected I am using Handler to write/read from the stream. Here is the handler code. For the `connectedThread` and `ConnectThread`, I have used the same as in the Android Developer example. However, I am not sure when to call both `read()` and `write()` methods and where usually messages exchanged between the two connected devices are stored?

```
Handler mhandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.i(tag, "in handler");
            String s = myapplication.getMessage();
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            connectedThread.run();
            switch (msg.what){
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    //ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readbuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String string = new String(readbuf);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of code into the question, using the code tags. Start with the smallest working example.

Comment: @KLibby Thank you. I am posting it. Hope you can help.